# Adding a link to dynamic div elements only distinguishable by background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is my first question here - hope I included all the necessary info. I'm currently trying to add a link to a div element generated automatically through Drupal. The element is a carousel with different slides. Each slide contains only one image that is automatically set as background-image. The different slides don't have singular ids or something else I could address, so the only difference between them is the linked background image.

My aim is to add a link to each slide. Unfortunately, I don't have any control over the carousel element nor any of the divs, that's why I'm looking for solutions that can be added via javascript / css. My first guess would be to try identifying the right element with document.quereSelector(css_selector) and combining that with an event listener. My idea looks something like this:

```
document.querySelector(css_selector).addEventListener('click', function() {
location.href = 'target-url.com'}, false);
```

This is what the carousel looks like on the page:

```html
<div class="carousel-block“><div class="slide carousel carousel-hero" id="XX" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  </div> 
  <div class="item carousel-slide" style="background-image: url('URL1.jpg')">
  <div class="block-text">
    <div class="middle">
      <h3></h3>
      <div class="description"></div>
          </div>
  </div>
      </div> 
<div class="item carousel-slide" style="background-image: url('URL2.jpg')">
  <div class="block-text">
    <div class="middle">
      <h3></h3>
      <div class="description"></div>
          </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Would that solution work? I'm not completely sure on the css_selector either. Would be great, if you could hint me in the right direction.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any idea on how you want to place the right url on the right element? I don't see a way you are going to know what url to place on each element

Comment: Is there a way for you to connect the background-image URL to the link URL? Is the correlation between those constant? If it is, then it can be done and I can show you how.

Comment: That is exactly my problem - is it possible to use (div style="background-image: url(background-img url('URL1.jpg'}) to identify the right image?

Comment: @SomeRandomName Unfortunately not - the best I could to is to change the image url alias to something else. Would that help you?

Comment: Maybe I've said it wrong - I want to know if for example the div with URL1.png will ALWAYS point to the same link, same for URL2.png and other images.

Comment: @SomeRandomName You got it right - the div with URL1.png will always point to link 1, the div with URL2.png to link2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not completely wrong. You just need to add event for all the slide div.
But in your code you have use document.querySelector(css_selector) which will add click event to only first div. You have to use document.querySelectorAll(css_selector). This will give array of elements and then you have to loop threw those elements and attach click event. See below examples.

1. If you want to open same link on all the slide then you can do something like below

> ```
> document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide').forEach(function(slide) {
>       slide.addEventListener('click',  function() {
>           location.href = 'target-url.com';
>       }, false)
>   });
> ```

2. If you want different link based on background image then you can do something like below.

> ```
> document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide').forEach(function(slide) {
>           slide.addEventListener('click', function(ele) {
>               var image = ele.target.closest('div.carousel-slide').style.backgroundImage;
>               image= image.replace('url("', '').replace('")', '');
>               var url;
>               switch(image) {
>                   case 'URL1.jpg': 
>                       url = 'link 1';
>                       break;
>                   case 'URL2.jpg': 
>                       url = 'link 2';
>                       break;      
>               }
>               location.href = url;
>           }, false)
>       });
> ```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer! It correctly identifies the carousel-slide elements and adds a link to them. Unfortunately, the script can't identify the correct background image (URL1.jpg), no matter whether it is the right image or not, the link used is always the 'target-url.com'. Do you have an idea why that might happen?

Comment: Hey sorry, i just forget to replace 'target-url.com' with url in the above example 2. you can get url based on image. I have edited the answer you can try that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I misunderstood the location.href apparently.